# Getting tr id for td elements in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, getelementbyid

I have the following JS function:

```
function drawItNow() {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
  for (i = 1; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
    if document.getElementById(inputs[i].id).parentNode.id = 'svgpic'; {
      if (inputs[i].id != "") {
        var tdidtemp = inputs[i].id;
        fillHtml(tdidtemp, valArray[i - 1].xVal, valArray[i - 1].yVal, valArray[i - 1].padVal, valArray[i - 1].fillVal, valArray[i - 1].heightVal, valArray[i - 1].coltext, valArray[i - 1].xAxStart, valArray[i - 1].xAxStop);
      } else {

      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to check if the tr for the td is has the id of `svgpic`. 
The rest of the function works fine so there must be something wrong with that check.

As an alternative I also tried:

```
if inputs[i].id.closest('tr').attr('id')='svgpic';{
```

but that had the same problem.

Comment: for comparisson you should use `==` or `===` not `=`.  in both the if statements, you are assigning values instead of comparing

Comment: This Javascript is all over the place: you have no parens around your `if` condition, you have a semicolon before your opening brace in the `if` block, and you get an element by its own ID, which is redundant and adds to the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When comparing we use `==` or `===`.  you have used `=` which is an assignment operation.  you if statements should be

```
if (document.getElementById(inputs[i].id).parentNode.id === 'svgpic') {
      if (inputs[i].id !== "") {
```